# Using CFBundleDocumentTypes: why does my app not show up in the "Share" menu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to register my app for all possible file types. I added the following to my info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.data</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <string>public.content</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

If I now open a PDF in Safari and tap Safari's "Share" button, my app is not offered. However if I tap the PDF itself, a button "Open In" appears on top and there my app is listed.

This is not a real problem but it prevents users to import photos into my app, because there is no "Open In" menu in the Photos app.

Can I register for the "Share" menu too somehow?

Comment: can u pls provide me example for the same. i am looking for the same solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible, because:

The share screen in Safari is using `UIActivityViewController` to display a number of activities that can be performed with the page. Those activities are defined in `UIActivity.h` and are usually the system-defined activities such as *Post to Facebook*, *Post to Twitter*, *Message*, *Print*, etc.

For an non-system defined activity to appear in that screen, one has to create a custom `UIActivity` subclass and then initialize the `UIActivityViewController` with an array of these.

The "Open In..." screen on the other hand looks similar but is using a `UIDocumentInteractionController` which displays apps that can open the given URL/[UTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Type_Identifier) (don't Google UTI...)

Comment: But that's the other way round. What I want: _my_ app in _Safari's_ "Share" menu.

Comment: Which is not possible because UIActivityViewController does not display apps, only system-provided services.

Comment: For your app to appear in that Share screen, Safari engineers would have to create a custom UIActivity class that, when tapped, will launch your app.

Comment: If you update your answer, explaining that it is not possible, I can accept it.

Comment: OK, I've added a statement at the beginning of this answer :-)